# CamelCorrelationID/JMS CorrelationID implementation

Tags: apache-camel, jms, message-queue

I am confused how to implement CamelCorrelationID/JMSCorrelationID in a way where each application listen to its own response from server using messaging system. The queues are shared in this scenario. I have implemented my own CorrelationID to maintain the state of application. here I am using two client applications (Client-A and Client-B) sending/receiving the request to/from server

Currently both applications are reading each other responses from server, instead each application should listens to its own response based on CorrelationID passed in the header of request message.

Need help to resolve this.

Below are the code details:

Client-A code:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.12</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.camel.a</groupId>
    <artifactId>CorrelationId-A</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CorrelationId-A</name>
    <description>Understanding CorrelationId</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <camel.version>3.11.0</camel.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>  
            <version>${camel.version}</version>     
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-amqp-starter</artifactId>  
            <version>${camel.version}</version>         
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

ClientARequestRoute.java

```
package com.camel.a.route;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ClientARequestRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1")
        .process(new Processor() {          
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
                String uniqueId = uuid.toString();
                String testMsg = "Sending message from Client A with Unique Id as - " + uniqueId;               
                exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CORRELATION_ID, uniqueId);
                exchange.getIn().setBody(testMsg, String.class);
            }           
        })
        .log("${body}")
        .to("amqp:queue:RequestQueue");     
    }
}
```

ResponseServerRoute.java

```
package com.camel.a.route;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ResponseServerRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        from("amqp:queue:ResponseQueue")
        .process(new Processor() {          
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                                
                String uniqueId = (String)exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.CORRELATION_ID);
                System.out.println("Received Correlation Id - " + uniqueId);
                String msgReceived = (String) exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);                               
                exchange.getIn().setBody(msgReceived);
            }           
        })
        .log("${body}")
        .end();     
    }
}
```

Client-B code:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.12</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.camel.b</groupId>
    <artifactId>CorrelationId-B</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CorrelationId-B</name>
    <description>Understanding CorrelationId</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <camel.version>3.11.0</camel.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>  
            <version>${camel.version}</version>     
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-amqp-starter</artifactId>  
            <version>${camel.version}</version>         
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

ClientBRequestRoute.java

```
package com.camel.b.route;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.ExchangePattern;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ClientBRequestRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1")
        .process(new Processor() {          
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
                String uniqueId = uuid.toString();
                String testMsg = "Sending message from Client B with Unique Id as - " + uniqueId;               
                exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CORRELATION_ID, uniqueId);
                exchange.getIn().setBody(testMsg, String.class);
            }           
        })
        .log("${body}")
        .to("amqp:queue:RequestQueue"); 
    }
}
```

ResponseServerRoute.java

```
package com.camel.b.route;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ResponseServerRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {      
        from("amqp:queue:ResponseQueue")
        .process(new Processor() {          
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                                
                String uniqueId = (String)exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.CORRELATION_ID);
                System.out.println("Received Correlation Id - " + uniqueId);
                String msgReceived = (String) exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);                               
                exchange.getIn().setBody(msgReceived);
            }           
        })
        .log("${body}")
        .end();     
    }
}
```